# Js canvas manipulation with asset manager

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, asset-management

I want to create a basic image js manipulation problem. Well not that basic. My requirements are

1. Image loaded after clicked by user
2. User can edit this image(contrast invert filter rotation)
3. User can use a dialog that displays some other smaller images. These images (fixed size) can be placed by clicking (or drag n dropped) on original first image
4. Images placed on original image can be rotated or moved.

I think fabric has what I want(rotating with anchors etc), but it doesn't include an asset manager? Is there a js library that has all these or is there a stand alone asset manager that can work well with fabricjs?

Comment: FabricJS has `canvas.toDataURL` which serializes the current canvas to a dataUrl. From there you can send the dataUrl to an asset manager of your choosing on your server.

Comment: I was thinking of the asset manager that loads the static images that will be used from the JavaScript app. Kinda like when a game is loading.